# VSCode: How can I disable the windowframe so maximized looks like full screen?

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-code

How can I disable the window frame on `vscode` so that there is no bevel and the window looks as if it is in full screen? It might not be fully clear what I am getting at but I have posted some pictures that will hopefully make more sense.

Maximized with a bevel:

[image: maximized_bevel]

Full screen with no bevel:

[image: full-screen_no-bevel]

I don't these changes are possible via the GUI and envisage that it needs some changes in the `settings.json` file, possibly via customised `.css` and `.js`...

That's my hunch, but not sure if this is true or what to do. I have tried [customize-UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui) and [Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css) without luck, so was hoping I could get some guidance on here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you could try Zen Mode. This feature gets rid of all UI elements except the editor.

To activate Zen Mode, go to **View -> Appearance -> Zen Mode** or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>cmd</kbd>+ <kbd>K Z</kbd>. To view the top bar, click the alt/option key

Comment: Thanks @Sony, but I did not want to have the app in full-screen as on MacOS it creates a new desktop space. Essentially, I wanted to remove the frame around the app at all times. I have this in my Emacs setup and was hoping it was possible for VSCode. I just find it less distracting…

Comment: Oh. If you go to View -> Appearance, there is an option for show sidebar and show menu bar that is selected by default. You can unselect those to get rid of them.

Comment: No, that's what I was after. I don't think it is possible via the GUI and envisage that it needs some changes for the `settings.json` file, possibly via customised `.css` and `.js`... That's my hunch, but not sure if this is true or what to do. I have tried [customize-UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui) and [Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css) without luck, so was hoping I could get some guidance on here. @Sony, I have added more detail to my OP to reflect this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To toggle fullscreen just press fn+F11 and you'll be fine.

Answer (score -1):

With the Bevel you mean this kind of Border?

[image]

I'm wondering how this could be removed, I always switch into fullscreen mode to remove it.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33874814)